# Adverbial position

Tags: grammar, adverbs, adverbial-phrases

I've found a newspaper caption reading:

> They organised *on Monday* a meeting.

I would have expected the caption to be

> They organised a meeting *on Monday*.

Which one of the above is correct?

Comment: Welcome here! Are you asking about they vs. we or about the placement of the time phrase? Btw, you question could benefit from a bit of formatting to clarify what exactly are the quotes.

Comment: Sorry in both cases the subjects are They. And asking about the time phrase

Comment: ...organised on Monday a meeting vs organised a meeting on Monday

Comment: Are you sure the direct object wasn't longer? It is a bit odd as it is written in the question, because the diret object is too short. Consider ***They organised on Monday a meeting of the 27th International Proletariate Guardian Readers Convention***, which sound much better!

Answer (score 1):

You are right. The standard English is:

> They organized a meeting on Monday.

Or:

> On Monday, they organized a meeting.

By the way, I don't know who wrote the caption you saw, but it is not surprising to see English learners putting adverbials in non-standard sentence positions, because English grammar often allows them to be placed in multiple locations.